# Gravity and collision detection not working well in DrRacket

Tags: scheme, racket, collision-detection, 2d-games, gravity

While trying to implement gravity in my "Donkey Kong" game, i ran into a problem. The jump movement works perfectly fine when Mario is on a platform. But however when he's falling from one platform to another, the collision with the next platform doesn't get detected and so mario goes through the platform.
This is how my gravity logic works: The vertical velocity is checked every frame, if it's not equal to 0 then mario is moved (+ mario-y vVelocity). As long as there is no collision with a platform, the vVelocity is changed to (- vVelocity gravity). And when there is a collision with a platform, the vVelocity gets reset to 0. The problem with this is, the mario-y changes too much every frame, for example it can go from (100;100) to (100;90) when the vVelocity= -10, and if there is a platform in (100;95), the collision is not detected. How can i fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There at least two options.

1. Introduce a maximum velocity smaller than the size of a platform. In this way the player can’t pass a platform without a collision.
2. Use two or more time steps when you update the variables. So far your time step had the same duration as a frame. If you split the frame into several steps the velocity per time step will be smaller - as a result the player won’t move through a platform without a collision.

Answer (score 0):

You should create line between last and current position and check  line/platform intersection for collisions.
Also this is not Racket specific but general discrete simulation problem.